# How to call async functions in Stream.periodic

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to call an async function inside dart:Stream.periodic function?

I tried to wrap my async function but it is not working, please see code below.

```dart
Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: _pollingInterval), _checkConnectivity)

String _checkConnectivity(int x) async {

return await _connectionRepository.checkConnection();

}
```

Comment: You can't call the async function inside the stream

Comment: Have the function return a Future and be non-async. Use the Future in the next part of the stream chain.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use asyncMap:

```dart
  Stream<String> checkConnectionStream() async* {
    yield* Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: _pollingInterval), (_) {
      return _connectionRepository.checkConnection();
    }).asyncMap((event) async => await event);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with dart streams yet, but you should be able to simulate what you're trying to achieve like this:

```dart
final controller = StreamController<String>();

Timer timer;
controller.onListen = () {
  timer = Timer.periodic(
    _pollingInterval,
    (timer) => _connectionRepository.checkConnection().then((data){ 
       if(!controller.isClosed){
         controller.add(data);
       }
    }),
  );
};
controller.onCancel = () {
  timer?.cancel();
}

return controller.stream;
```

The stream does not support pause and continue, though. If you want that you'd need to override the corresponding callbacks on the controller and start/stop the timer there.

Also, depending on the timing of `checkConnection` this can result in events in the stream being very different to `_pollingInterval`.